# How to debug C++ with MSYS2 (MSYS64) gdb.exe on VSCode?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I can't get the C++ (GDB) debugger to work.
So far, I'd instaled the extensions:

- [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner)
- [C/C++](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)
- [C++ Intellisense](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=austin.code-gnu-global)

MSYS2 is already in Windows PATH, and I can call gdb.exe from PowerShell with:

```
Start("gdb.exe")
```

By the first time I tried, I got a message that the **crtexe.c** didn't exists. I choose the option to create it. The file path is on `C:\repo\mingw-w64-crt-git\src\mingw-w64\mingw-w64-crt\crt\crtexe.c` and I've copied its contents from this [source](https://github.com/msys2-contrib/mingw-w64/blob/master/mingw-w64-crt/crt/crtexe.c).

The programs is compiling fine. And, when pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>, the debugger jumps to *crtexe.c* and stops after few <kbd>F11</kbd> steps. I'm really stuck at this point and any help will be, indeed, more than appreciated !

This is my **c_cpp_properties.json**:

```js
{
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Mac",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "/usr/include",
                "/usr/local/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "/usr/include",
                    "/usr/local/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include-fixed",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wrl",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/tr1",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/backward",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0",
                "C:/msys64/mingw64/include",
                "${workspaceRoot}"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "__GNUC__=7.1.0",
                "__cdecl=__attribute__((__cdecl__))"
            ],
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/include-fixed",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/x86_64-w64-mingw32",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/wrl",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/tr1",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0/backward",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/7.1.0",
                    "C:/msys64/mingw64/include",
                    "${workspaceRoot}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }
        }
    ],
    "version": 2
}
```

And, my **launch.json** is like that:

```js
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [{
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was just a question of edit the *workspace* **settings.json** like follows. That way, with the `-g`option, the compiler inserts debug symbols on the program and the debugger works fine.

```js
{
    "code-runner.executorMap": {
        "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt -g && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
    }
}
```

Problem apparently solved!